# Correct way to make a title a link

Tags: theme-development, links

I made the title of my post excerpt a link to the full content. It works but whenever I validate my website, the validator marks it wrong and shows the message below. I've switched around the h2 tags and it still didn't help.

**document type does not allow element "h2"**

The code looks as shown b elow

```
    <span class="home-post-header"> 

      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">

          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        </a> </span><!-- End Home Post Header  -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice one for using WordPress, but this is a straight-up HTML question. Nontheless...

```
<div class="home-post-header"> 
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

`h2`'s are considered block-level, whereas `a` & `span` are inline. Standards dictate that a block-level element cannot be nested inside an inline one. So use a `div` instead, & place the `a` *inside* the `h2`.

N.B:  With HTML5, nesting block-level elements inside `a` is valid, but IMO use only when you need to wrap a link around several elements (for example, a heading with an image or snippet).